# Опечатка или ошибка в библиотеке http://msdn.microsoft.com ?

Tags: c

Как мне видится, диапазон генерируемых чисел будет [1,11] не так ли!? (Наткнулся на сайте Microsoft)

```
// Display 10 random integers in the range [ 1,10 ].
for( i = 0; i < 10;i++ )
{
    err = rand_s( &number );
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf_s("The rand_s function failed!\n");
    }
    printf_s( "  %u\n", (unsigned int) ((double)number /
                      (double) UINT_MAX * 10.0) + 1);
}
```

Comment: В общем-то да, скорее - опечатка в комментарии, хотя `[a,b]` можно интерпретировать и так: `a` - смещение, `b` - длина.

Comment: Всё, буду звонить биллу ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строго говоря, [1, 11]. Хотя 11 будет выходить только когда number==UINT_MAX, что будет происходить очень редко.

Comment: Почему это очень редко? Разве не с вероятностью p=(1/11) !?

Comment: нет, потому что 11 получите только в том случае, когда number == UINT_MAX. А вот будет ли оно ему равно - это ещё нужно проверить. поэтому вероятность либо 0, либо 1/UINT_MAX, что очень мало.

Comment: При этом вся гнусность в том, что ошибка будет выявляться редко. Хорошо, если не метко )))

Comment: И как бороться с багом? Хочется все-таки uniform distribution...

Comment: >Хотя 11 будет выходить только когда number==UINT_MAX
Точно чаще,  
все же округляется, поэтому отношение `>= 0,96` тоже даст `11`, а это куча значений диапазона `UINT`. Конечно, это еще зависит от выбранной модели округления `FPU`.

Comment: Решил пойти эмпирическим путём:

    unsigned int number, newNumber; 
    long long int iter=0;
    while(1)
    {
      rand_s( &number );
      newNumber=(unsigned int) ((double)number /(double) UINT_MAX * 2.0) + 1;
      if (newNumber==3)
      {
        std::cout<<iter;
        std::cin>>iter;
      }
      iter++;
    }

Через некоторое время получил - 440 045 845, явно пахнет не равномерным распределением! :)

Comment: >Решил пойти эмпирическим путём

На самом деле, достаточно было сделать простую операцию:

 double x = 0.95;
 double y = 10.0*x;
 int z = (int)y;

В случае, если округление дает `z = 9`, то распределение неравномерное, если `10` - равномерное. В случае неравномерного распределения ,его можно попробовать выровнять, установив `_MCW_RC` через `_controlfp_s` в `_RC_NEAR`. Если компилятор честный, то он будет использовать команды FPU `fld/fist`. В таком случае `9.95` даст `10`.